# SQL Server Clustered Index: Unique vs. Increasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

Hello StackOverflow Community.

I am currently redesigning a SQL Server DB Table that has to store time based values. The old table was getting around 50,000,000 entries per day which became simply too much. Therefore we are planning to group the entries hourly which will result in around 5,000 entries per day.

My concept of the new table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data.Values (
    Date date NOT NULL, /* The day of the values */
    Hour tinyint NOT NULL, /* The hour of the values */
    DeviceId int NOT NULL, /* The id of the gateway that these values belong to */
    Values varbinary(MAX) NOT NULL /* The actual values in binary format */
);
```

New data is simply appended to the existing in the *Values* property in binary, depending on the *timestamp* and *deviceId* of the data.

My problem is to find a good clustered index for this table. As I read, the most important criteria for a clustered index are:

- narrow
- static
- **unique**
- **ever-increasing**

The first two points can be easily covered by any index candidate, as the written data is never modified and there are only a few columns. My two options are:

- If I use the **(Date, Hour, DeviceId)** combination as clustered index, then it will **not** be **ever-increasing**, as the data from various devices (and thus various device IDs) will be written. Only the Date+Hour is ever-increasing. But this combination is **unique**.
- So if I use the **(Date, Hour)** combination, then the index is **ever-increasing** but **not unique** anymore, because there are other deviceIds that use the same time.

**Shortly**: Is there preference if I have to decide between a **unique** or **ever-increasing** index?

Thank you for your expertises!

**EDIT**: I noticed that I might have explained the insert situation badly. There have been many inserts in the old table which will result in updates on the *values* column on the new table design. But since this column is not indexed it should not hurt the performance as far as I understood that.

Comment: In my opinion, `UNIQUE` isn't something that is a contributing factor to a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, though it is often a "happy coincidence", due to the index ever increasing (especially when using something like an `IDENTITY` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID`).

Comment: Don't design in a vacuum for a single purpose. You have only one clustered index. You choose it based on how the rows are inserted/modified/deleted and how you need to query the table to get useful information. The choice of a clustered index has been discussed many times - suggest you research first. And using a blob for your "data" is suspicious, but only you know what you do with it. And don't equate clustered index with primary key (or unique key). Keys should be enforced - clustering is a different decision.

Comment: I did research before asking here, but I couldn't find out if there is a preference between either having an unique or increasing clustered index. Data is written subsequently with timestamps that are at most 15 minutes old. The data is then never updated again. There is also only one query that is used on the table: ```SELECT * FROM data.Values WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN ... AND ... AND deviceId=123```. It is no problem to have a few more values than requested, so writing it in binary prevents unnecessary granularity in the time domain.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `Date`, `Hour`, and `DeviceId` will be unique given your explanation. When using multiple columns as an index, the columns are combined. Being a clustered index dictates how the records are sorted when inserting new records.

Comment: yes this combination is unique. I forgot to mention that in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Because we are talking about a clustered index, it has to be narrow and static. This index will also determine the sorting order. That's logical.

If it is not unique, SQL Server will make it unique. This is done under the hood with a UNIQUIFIER key. This key will be 4 extra bytes long. (so a bit less narrow) For mor information search "UNIQUIFIER and sql server".

If the key is not ever-increasing the inserts will not always be at the end. This results in page splits and cost a bit more time to insert. When doing a lot of inserts page splits will hurt your performance.

If the key is ever-increasing the insert will always be done at the end. This would be my preference because in your question you are talking about a lot of inserts. But...

If you always insert at the end you might run into locking problems. Search for "Last Page Insert Latch Contention. Because concurrent inserts will have to write in the same 8K-page. You can also search in google for "ever-increasing clusterd key doesn't scale! Fortunately there is a solution to address this problem. You can read an answer in StackExchange. Link: https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/04/15/an-ever-increasing-clustered-key-value-doesnt-scale/

This answer fits your question because you do have a varbinary(max) in your table too. Please search for "What is the best practice for storing image varbinary(max) data in a database table?" Here is the link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/what-is-the-best-practice-for-storing-image-varbinarymax-data-in-a-database-ta

The answer mentioned there is to set "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF".

Another good article is this link: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

I've read all three articles and I think that I'll go with your advice and the one mentioned in the third article "... like a datetime column (or since that's NOT very likely to be unique by itself datetime, identity)".

So if I use (date, hour) then the DB will add an identifier to this combination itself since it is not unique. So I'll have an ever increasing clustered index by that right?